# Recovery of cryptocurrency sent to scam trading platforms went off-line

Tags: blockchain

I Transfer Cryptocurrency to trading platform that turned out to be a scam and went off-line. Is there any possibility of recovering the deposits? Was ETH deposit to
0x9d87a66418bf572569cefc7acf0c0c562c69465fec455d4803867521b1d6461a

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear about your situation. Unfortunately, due to blockchain's immutable nature, it's highly unlikely that you'll be able to recover your funds.

When you sent your ETH to that address, the ownership of those funds was transferred to whoever controls that address. If the platform was a scam, tracking down the owners or forcing them to return your funds is near impossible.

Blockchain transactions are irreversible once confirmed. While this ensures transaction integrity, it also means there's little recourse if something goes wrong.

You can report this to local law enforcement and provide them all details, but the process might not result in fund recovery. In the future, consider using well-reputed and secure platforms for your transactions.